# What is the (big O) complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, complexity-theory

The code searches for the number of possible pathways of actions that reach the goal. I do not want to optimize it, just know the Big-O complexity that it has. The code is the following:

```
private int countPaths(Node parent, List<Action> usableActions, Node goal)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach(Action act in usableActions)
    {
        Node node = generateNewNode(parent, act); // Only generate the new node O(1)
        if (node.isEquals(goal)) //Check goal
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Action> subset = actionSubset(usableActions, act); // return usableAction with act removed
            counter += countPaths(node, subset, goal); // usableActions - 1
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

The first loop would give the algorithm a complexity of O(n), but having a recursive call does not know if it is O(n^2), O(n^n) or another option.

Comment: Start [here](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

Comment: it seems to be On!, but I'm not an expert on this... This would be my guess

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here. It looks like you are trying to count the number of different paths in a graph which is dynamically generated. As far as we know at this point this need not even terminate, as the goal may never be reached.

Comment: @HenningKoehler it will terminate because even if nothing matches the goal, the list of values being evaluated is reduced by 1 element with every recursive call. I think Leaonardo Alves Machado is correct - this looks like O(n!) in the worst case.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams Oh, you're right. And yes, O(n!) should be the best worse-case upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in some of the comments, the *time complexity* is [image: O(n!)].

As for *memory usage*, `actionSubset()` creates a new list each time it is called (as opposed to having the algorithm operate on the original). But because all lists except the original fall out of scope at the end of each iteration, memory usage will only grow by [image: n] as a function of the size of `usableActions`, so [image: n!].